# diffrentiation wrt to z bar operator

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find $\partial_{\overline{z}}(\frac{z}{z-w})$ .I am getting two different answers. First I tried to do the product rule taking one of the function as $z$ and other as $z-w$ .The answer I got was $z\delta(z-w)$.

Then I tried to rewrite the function as $ 1 + \frac{w}{z-w}$ and then did the diffrentiation .The answer I got was $w\delta(z-w)$.

In both the cases I used the fact $\partial_{\overline{z}}(\frac{1}{z-w})=\delta(z-w)$.
Am I doing something wrong?Please help me

Comment: You should be getting zero. The point is that $\partial_{\overline z}f(z)=0$ for any holomorphic $f$, as that's the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: From the notation, it seems that the OP is differentiating in the distribution sense @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: If that's the Dirac delta then then surely $g(z)\delta(z-a)=g(a)\delta(z-a)$? @JohnMa

Comment: Yes @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed $z\delta(z-w) = w \delta (z-w)$ since for any test functions $\varphi$,

$$ w\delta (z-w) \varphi = w \varphi (w) $$

and

$$ z\varphi (z-w) \varphi = \delta(z-w) (z\varphi) = w\varphi (w).$$